# Enum for number in GraphQL (js)

Tags: graphql

I want to allow one of the fields to be either 1, 2 or 3. I am not exactly sure how to do that in [http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/](http://GraphQL-JS)

Because I would need to do something like:

```
var AgeType = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'Age',
  values: {
    1: { value: 0 },
    2: { value: 1 },
    3: { value: 2 }
  }
});
```

And this doesn't work because the key is a number...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as described here: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/issues/586

> GraphQL require enum values to match [_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z] RegExp

Enum variables have to start with a letter, so you will have to use String or Int type. In order to ensure that only 1,2 and 3 are passed, you may implement some kind of validation rules in the resolvers.